# Can't start Thread Profiler in NewRelic on a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, newrelic

I have a Spring Boot 3.1.5 application based on Java 17. This app is dockerized and executed in a Kubernetes 1.27.x cluster in Azure AKS. I use the New Relic Java agent v8.7.0.

I want to launch the thread profiling in the New Relic UI. So I choose the duration, the JVM and I click on "Start profiler".

After a minute, I saw in the newrelic logs this trace:

```
2023-11-16T08:15:33,525+0000 [1 86] com.newrelic.agent.commands.CommandParser ERROR: Unable to parse command : com.newrelic.agent.commands.CommandException: sample_period > duration in start_profiler command: 3,788,899 > 0.1
```

Do you have any idea why I have this parsing command error?

Comment: It looks like it is a bug on New Relic's backend. It is being investigated.

Comment: Do you have an ETA for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a bug in New Relic's backend and was fixed early December.